# How to load symbols from a symbol server in Ghidra?

Tags: disassembly, windows, binary-analysis, decompilation, ghidra

I've been trying to learn [Ghidra](https://www.nsa.gov/resources/everyone/ghidra/) by attempting to reverse the `comctl32.dll` system library, which has many of its functions documented. I started the de-compilation analysis in it, and after a while it showed this error message:

*(I don't know how soon it happened. I had to leave it to do its thing as sadly it was taking too long.)*

[image]

Then I happened to see that if I go to File -> Download PDB file, then select some folder on my drive and provide Microsoft symbol path `https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols` and click `"Download from URL"` it seems to download it.

It then asks if I want to apply it to the project and if I click `Yes` it shows this warning:

[image]

So I'm obviously not doing it right.

Thus I was curious:

A) Is it possible to provide the symbol server path and have it download needed symbol files automatically?

B) If not, what's the sequence to load symbols for a particular binary? It seems like it wants to have symbols up front, but how would I know which files/imports it may need (besides the obvious binary file that I'm opening)?

Answer (score 3):

One of the possible ways to do this - use [radare2](https://github.com/radareorg/radare2) or [Cutter](https://github.com/radareorg/cutter) with the [r2ghidra](https://github.com/radareorg/r2ghidra-dec) plugin. It will load the PDB and use Ghidra decompiler to do the actual decompilation.

Answer (score 2):

Yea, it's not completely automatic like IDA Pro.
Although the NSA dev team is very active on the project. And any US citizen should be able to add such a feature (via Java) and make a pull request to add it.

I found what you do is simply add the module to your Ghidra project.
When you click on the module/executable it will ask "...Would you like to analyze it now?".
Click "No", load your PDB, and then start the analysis manually via the "Analysis" menu option.

Comment: "any US citizen"?

Comment: >>"any US citizen"? It's understanding they IP block some countries, I could be be wrong. Your welcome.

Comment: IP-block? I thought it runs locally on your computer & you can download it from GitHub. What do you mean?

Comment: @c00000fd: it's a legal requirement, not technical